# Google Chart: How do I sort by category filter with chronological order (by month)?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a category filter that populates month name with alphabetical order. I would like to display the months by chronological order (January, February, March, etc.) and also I would like to set current month name as default in the dropdown. I can not tweak the SQL by `ORDER BY` field, instead, I would like to do it from category filter.

**Code:**

```
var filterFrequencyData = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper(
{
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filterFrequencyDataHtml',
    'options':
        {
            'filterColumnIndex': '5',
            'ui':
                {
                    'label': '',
                    'labelSeparator': ':',
                    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                    'allowTyping': false,
                    'allowNone': false,
                    'allowMultiple': false,
                    'sortValues': false
                }
        }
});
```

[image: Category Filter Snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `sortValues: false` on a [CategoryFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#categoryfilter), the values will be sorted as they appear in the data.

In order to get the month names to sort in *chronological order (January, February, March, etc...),* you need to use a column type other than `'string'` and sort that column, `'number'` or `'date'`, for instance.

Then set the formatted value of the cell to the month name. For example:

```
{v: 0, f: 'January'}
```

or

```
{v: new Date(2016, 0, 1), f: 'January'}
```

You can also use the `setFormattedValue` method, if the cell already has a value:

```
data.setFormattedValue(0, 0, 'January');
```

once in place, the table can be sorted according to the `'number'` or `'date'`:

```
data.sort({column: 0});
```

See the following working snippet, a `'date'` column is used to sort the month names:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [{
        label: 'Month',
        type: 'date'
      }]
    });

    // load months in reverse
    var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMMM'});
    var today = new Date();
    var monthCount = 12;
    var selectedRow;
    var rowIndex;
    while (monthCount--) {
      // get row values
      var monthDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), monthCount, 1);
      var monthName = formatDate.formatValue(monthDate);

      // use object notation when setting value
      rowIndex = data.addRow([{
        // value
        v: monthDate,

        // formatted value
        f: monthName
      }]);

      // set selected row
      if (monthName === formatDate.formatValue(today)) {
        selectedRow = rowIndex;
      }
    }

    // sort data
    data.sort({column: 0});

    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
      containerId: 'control_div',
      options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 0,
        ui: {
          allowMultiple: false,
          allowNone: false,
          allowTyping: false,
          label: '',
          labelStacking: 'vertical',
          sortValues: false
        },
        // use month name
        useFormattedValue: true
      },
      // state needs formatted value
      state: {
        selectedValues: [data.getFormattedValue(selectedRow, 0)]
      }
    });

    // or set state here -- just need month name
    control.setState({selectedValues: [formatDate.formatValue(today)]});

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'chart_div',
      options:{
        allowHtml: true
      }
    });

    dash.bind(control, chart);
    dash.draw(data);
  },
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart', 'table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="control_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me give a try. :)